# How do I assign a probability (uniform increasing or decreasing linear distribution) to a array of values?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Given X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] -- **but X could be any length(N)**.
>
> I want to achieve the following:
>
> 1. I want to give the 1st value X[0], the highest probability.
> 2. I want to give the 2nd value X[1], a lesser probability than X[0].
> 3. I want to give the 3rd value X[2], a lesser probability than X[1].
> 4. ...
> 5. I want to give the Last value X[N], a lesser probability than X[N-1]
>
> **All probabilities should sum up to 1.**

For clarity with uniform probability distribution(1/(X.length)) looks like this:

{1:0.1, 2:0.1, 3:0.1, 4:0.1, 5:0.1, 6:0.1, 7:0.1, 8:0.1, 9:0.1, 10:0.1,}. If possible solution in javascript would be Great.

Comment: There are uncountably infinitely many probability distributions that fit your requirements which you have written so far.  You will have to be more specific.  The uniform distribution over $n$ values is very easily seen to be the one that assigns a probability of $\frac{1}{n}$ to each, but for one which is decreasing there are too many to describe.  As for writing it in javascript, that is offtopic here.

Comment: For $n=3$ you could have for example $\frac{3}{6}, \frac{2}{6},\frac{1}{6}$ or you could have $\frac{5}{12}, \frac{4}{12}, \frac{3}{12}$.  Extending that idea should be easy to implement: just set the middle value (*or values if an even number*) to be $\frac{1}{n}$ (*or $\frac{1}{n}\pm \frac{\epsilon}{2}$*) and add or subtract $\epsilon$ from those to create each other number.  A completely different but equally simple distribution to implement is to have it be $\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon, \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\dots,\frac{1}{2^{n-1}},\frac{1}{2^n}-\epsilon$ where $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I see how there can be infinite distributions. if i start with middle value having 1/n probability. how do i find a  epsilon value that works.

Comment: @JMoravitz would epsilon of 1/2^n work for any n

Comment: Where the probabilities follow an arithmetic sequence... any value such that all appearing numbers are between zero and one., i.e. for odd $n$ you would require $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{n-1}{2}\epsilon\geq 0$, or written a different way, $0<\epsilon\leq \frac{2}{n^2-n}$.  My two examples for $n=3$ above I used $\epsilon=\frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{1}{12}$ respectively.  For even $n$, a similar statement can be constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X[N]$ a sequence of length $N$, start with any decreasing sequence of length $N$.

Just off the tip of my fingers, for example when $N=10$,
$$3476, 2349, 1987, 823, 521, 492, 170, 98, 57, 4
$$
Find their sum:
$$3476+2349+1987+823+521+492+170+98+57+ 4 = 9977
$$
Divide each by the sum:
$$\frac{3476}{9977}, \frac{2349}{9977}, \frac{1987}{9977}, \frac{823}{9977}, \frac{521}{9977}, \frac{492}{9977}, \frac{170}{9977}, \frac{98}{9977}, \frac{57}{9977}, \frac{4}{9977}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Does a half-triangular distribution work for you? It's pretty easy to define: let $Pr(X = k) = \frac{N-k+1}{M}$ for some $M$. Clearly this means that $Pr(X = 0) = \frac{N+1}{M}$, $Pr(X = 1) = \frac{N}{M}$, and so forth to $Pr(X = N - 1) = \frac{2}{M}$ and $Pr(X = N) = \frac{1}{M}$, so the descending requirement holds. Then all you need to do is find the $M$ such that it's a valid distribution:

$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k = 0}^{N}Pr(X = k) & = & 1 \\
\sum_{k = 0}^{N}\frac{N - k + 1}{M} & = & 1 \\
\frac{1}{M}\left((N+1)+N+\ldots+2+1\right) & = & 1 \\
M & = & T_{N+1} & = & \frac{(N+1)(N+2)}{2}
\end{eqnarray}$

Where $T_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is the $n$th triangular number.

So your probabilities are $Pr(X = k) = \frac{2(N - k + 1)}{(N + 1)(N + 2)}$.